# ¿Cómo funciona el {% block content %} en html Django?

Tags: html, python, django

Estoy siguiendo los tutoriales de Django de Algorisoft y veo que utiliza el `{% block content %}` para separar su código. Sin embargo, lo hago igual y no me funciona.A continuación parte del código que estoy usando en mi archivo "home.html"

```
<body class="hold-transition layout-top-nav">
  <div class="wrapper">
  
    {% include 'header.html' %}
  
      <div class='content-wrapper'>
          {% block content %}
  
          {% endblock %}
      </div>
  
    <!-- Control Sidebar -->
    <aside class="control-sidebar control-sidebar-dark">
      <!-- Control sidebar content goes here -->
      <div class="p-3">
        <h5>Title</h5>
        <p>Sidebar content</p>
      </div>
    </aside>
    <!-- /.control-sidebar -->
  
   {% include 'footer.html' %}
    <!-- Main Footer -->
  
  </div>
```

Esta es la prueba que tengo en mi archivo index (aclaro que es una prueba que estoy haciendo para entender el funcionamiento de el block content):

```
{% extends 'home.html' %}

{% block content %}

     <p>Hola</p>

{% endblock %}
```

Sin embargo en mi aplicación no me imprime el "Hola":
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo una imagen de cómo están ordenadas mis carpetas de templates:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si coloco el `<p> Hola </p>` fuera del `{% block content %}` en el código de mi "home.html" sí lo imprime en el servidor.

Comment: el `{% block loquesea %}` sirve para remplazar o cambiar una parte de la pagina o plantilla base principal cuando estás haciendo herencia de plantillas. Es decir si tienes un index.html principal donde tienes definido un bloque así `{% block loquesea %} hola {% endblock%}` y luego heredas de esa plantilla en un ejemplo.html, para cambiar ese "hola" especificamente de ese bloque, lo reemplazarias utilizando el mismo nombrado de bloque: `{% block loquesea %} nuevo hola {% endblock%}` y el resto de pagina se mantendria igual.

Comment: Hola. Entiendo lo que dices, pero estoy aplicándolo así como dices y no me funciona. He visto cómo lo hacen en tutoriales de YouTube y sigue sin funcionar :/. No sé qué estaré haciendo mal

Comment: Has probado agregando cualquier cosa al bloque en tu plantilla principal ? Talvez al no tener nada no lo está reconociendo django.

Comment: Voy  a probarlo y te cuento

Comment: Ya lo probé, pero me imprime lo que coloco en el bloque de mi plantilla principal :/

Answer (score -2):

prueba a renombrar tu fichero body.php por home.php y viceversa, hice el mismo tutorial y me paso lo mismo. El orden esta invertido.
Si revisas el codigo veras que el que llama a la template es body, no home.