# ¿Puedo ejecutar mi código linea por linea en VS Code?

Tags: python, vscode, depuración

Quisiera saber si puedo ejecutar mi código de Python y Html linea a linea en VS Code. A lo que me refiero es hacer algo parecido a lo que se puede hacer con el código en Microsoft Visual Basic.

Esta es la vista de VBA cuando se recorre el código paso a paso:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí dejo el enlace al [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hAOP83W1AOE) donde se muestra cómo hacerlo en VBA. Quisiera poder hacer algo similar en VS Code con los lenguajes que mencioné.

Comment: La [documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/debugging-python-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) de VScode dice que sí, que con la opción debug -- start debugging hace exactamente eso

Comment: Sí que se puede. Tienes que tener instalada la extensión para Python, pones un breakpoint en la línea en la que quieres que pare la ejecución y le das al icono de depuración (a la  izquierda, bajo el icono de Git). Más info --> https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

Answer (score 3):

Para hacer eso en VS Code y con Python debes tener instalada la extensión de Python que provee Microsoft, luego de eso usa la herramienta de Debug, si te fijas en la barra que esta a la izquierda del VS Code hay una fila de iconos, el de Debug es un insecto sobre un símbolo de play, das click en ese icono y luego en el botón Run and Debug.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tienes que tener en cuenta que para que funcione de la manera que quieres debes marcar Breakpoints en el código.

[image]

Los puntos rojos son los Breakpoints, cuando empieces a debuggear el código se detendrá en ellos, podrás ver el valor de las variables que quieras en tiempo real, también te aparecerá un pequeña barra con opciones debajo de la barra de titulo del VS Code, en ella verás unos botones para Parar, ir paso a paso, retroceder, etc. Con respecto a HTML no estoy seguro de que puedas hacerlo ya que HTML no es un lenguaje de programación.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias! Ha sido de mucha utilidad ¿Se puede hacer lo mismo con un código html?

Comment: Como te dije, el HTML no es un lenguaje de programación y por eso no creo que sea posible, si no estoy mal el navegador toma el código HTML, lo interpreta y muestra en pantalla lo que tiene que mostrar, creo que lo máximo que puedes hacer es usar las DevTools del navegador que estés usando, ¿por qué quieres ejecutar HTML linea por linea?

Comment: Lo quiero ejecutar linea por linea porque estoy teniendo un problema con un código que estoy haciendo en Django y no sé por qué no me funciona. Aquí está el problema: [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407947/c%c3%b3mo-funciona-el-block-content-en-html-django)